# Change tabindex depending on if a details element is open or closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and have been struggling with this for a while and would really appreciate any help.

I've got a details element that contains a link in the content and I want to toggle the tabindex depending on wether or not the details element is open or closed.

here's my html for the element

```
<details role="group">
 <summary role="button" aria-controls="details-content-1" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="summary">Details element that contains a link</span>
 </summary>
 <div class="content-panel" id="details-content-1">
  <p><a href="#" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Find out more</a>.</p>
 </div>
</details>
```

And I've got this jQuery, which sets a tabindex of -1 and toggles it when details is opened.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var linkIndex = "div.content-panel > p > a";

      $(linkIndex).attr("tabindex", "-1");
      $("details").click( function() {
        if ($ (linkIndex).attr("tabindex") == -1) {
          $ (linkIndex).attr("tabindex", 0);
        } else {
          $ (linkIndex).attr("tabindex", -1);
        }
      });
    });
```

The problem I've got is when I have more than one details element containing a link on a page. If I click one it'll also toggle the link in the other details element. Is there a way to get it to focus on the child of the details that's been clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.find()` to get the child `a` element and then update the tabindex. 
You have used `div.panel` instead of `div.content-panel`, please correct either in jquery or in html.

see below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      var linkIndex = "div.content-panel > p > a";

      $(linkIndex).attr("tabindex", "-1");
      $("details").click( function() {
        var $anchor = $(this).find('div.content-panel > p > a');
        if ($anchor.attr("tabindex") == -1) {
          $anchor.attr("tabindex", 0);
        } else {
          $anchor.attr("tabindex", -1);
        }
      });
    })
```

;

Comment: There is no div with the class `panel` it should be `content-panel`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, yes i have corrected it. Thanks

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for quick answer. And sorry, my mistake I've corrected my post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple of them you could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var linkIndex = "div.content-panel > p > a";

  $(linkIndex).attr("tabindex", "-1");
  $("details").click(function() {
    var content = $(this).find(linkIndex);
    if (content.attr("tabindex") == -1) {
      content.attr("tabindex", 0);
    } else {
      content.attr("tabindex", -1);
    }
  });
});
```

Please note I've changed `"div.panel > p > a";` to `"div.content-panel > p > a";`

**demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var linkIndex = "div.content-panel > p > a";

  $(linkIndex).attr("tabindex", "-1");
  $("details").click(function() {
    var content = $(this).find(linkIndex);
    if (content.attr("tabindex") == -1) {
      content.attr("tabindex", 0);
    } else {
      content.attr("tabindex", -1);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details role="group">
  <summary role="button" aria-controls="details-content-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="summary">Details element that contains a link</span>
  </summary>
  <div class="content-panel" id="details-content-1">
    <p><a href="#" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Find out more</a>.</p>
  </div>
</details>

<details role="group">
  <summary role="button" aria-controls="details-content-2" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="summary">Details element that contains a link</span>
  </summary>
  <div class="content-panel" id="details-content-2">
    <p><a href="#" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Find out more</a>.</p>
  </div>
</details>
```